# Scrapy python: ssl handshake failure

Tags: python, ssl, scrapy

I am getting handshake error for GET request as below:

```
scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.zomato.com/kochi/cafe-d-arabia-edappally/reviews#tabtop>: 
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
```

I am able to get response for the same page sometime and sometime i get above error.
I am sending request for say 30 and only 12 are being processed while rest fails with ssl handshake issue.

I am using Python 2.7.10, scrapy 1.04, python-twisted 15.2.1-1ubuntu2 on ubuntu 15.10

Can anyone pls guide me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you get the error only sometimes I would suggest that the problem is not in the client but either a load problem at the server or some network problems in between.

Comment: I am getting this error every time.